# Взаимодействие с outlook из другой программы

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

Предположим, в outlook приходит определенное письмо от определенного отправителя. Содержание этого письма необходимо передать в некоторую программу, а та в свою очередь на основании письма проделает какие то действия, а затем отправит письмо этому отправителю. Подскажите, как достигнуть такого поведения? P.s работе программы оутлкук это не должно мешать.

Answer (score 2):

У вас два варианта:

**1. Надстройка для Outlook**

Документация по созданию [**здесь**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb386094.aspx). По идее, если все правильно сделать, то мешать пользователю не должно. Недостатки: клиент обязан использовать Outlook, очень вероятно (не проверял) что надстройки привязаны к версии Outlook, для другого клиента придется мудрить что-то свое; письма будут обрабатываться только когда Outlook запущен, по факту обновления списка полученных писем.

**2. Через почтовый сервер**

Можно встроить в программу свой почтовый клиент.

- Почта на Exchange и пользователь в домене: можно сделать прозрачную для пользователя авторизацию, без ввода логина и пароля, но при этом пользователь будет обязан использовать именно эту почту для работы с данным адресатом.
- Произвольный почтовый сервер: необходима отдельная авторизация от имени пользователя в вашей программе.
- Можно завести для вашей программы отдельный почтовый адрес и настроить пересылку нужных писем на него. Это позволит использовать любой почтовый сервер и избавит пользователя от необходимости авторизоваться, но и отвечать программа будет не от имени пользователя, а от своего имени. Тут можно сделать подмену адреса отправителя или применить еще какой хак, но делать это нужно осторожно и правильно чтобы не попасть в спам-листы.

В любом случае вам придется самостоятельно искать нужные письма и отслеживать те, на которые ответ уже был отправлен вашей программой.

**3. Мини-сервер**

В этом варианте больше всего проблем, но на крайний случай можно попробовать.

Можно сделать из вашей программы подобие SMTP-сервера на который пересылать необходимые письма, на единственны адрес, обрабатывать по мере поступления и отправлять куда нужно, при этом, если ваши пользователи живут на внешней почте (mail, yandex, google и т.д.), ваша программа должна быть доступна из глобальной сети, но она может быть в единственном экземпляре для всех ваших пользователей.

Либо использовать технологию SMTP relay и завернуть на вашу программу весь поток отправляемой почты из которого фильтровать нужное - обрабатывать и отправлять дальше, ненужное - сразу отправлять дальше, но это будет работать только с внутренним почтовым сервером, к настройкам которого у вас есть доступ, и тоже с большой вероятностью приведет к попаданию в спам-листы, ну не любят спам-фильтры серверы пересылки, особенно открытые, исторически сложилось.

Comment: По варианту 2.3: если все делать правильно, никакого попадания в спам-листы не будет. "Правильно" означает, что программа должна отправлять ответы не напрямую - а через тот же самый SMTP relay, через который отправляет свои письма пользователь.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я имел ввиду попадание в спам при подмене адреса отправителя, гмыл у меня такое на дефолтных настройках заворачивает, независимо от сервера отправителя, почему не разбирался, незачем было. Но в целом согласен выкрутиться можно

Comment: Ни разу с гитхаба письменные комментарии не получали? Они там, между прочим, тоже с подменой адреса идут.

Answer (score -1):

Очевидно, что вам требуется устанавливать подключение с почтовым сервером отдельно от аутлука (он тут вообще не при чем), проходить авторизацию, парсить сообщения от нужных отправителей и работать с ними. Советую нагуглить EWS Managed API 2.0